# Near preimages, applicable to Bitcoin?

Tags: sha-256, cryptocurrency, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Bitcoin mining relies on generating a smaller hash than the so-called [*target*](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target) (a function of the so-called [*difficultly*](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty)), thus is vulnerable to a truncated preimage attack (you just need to obtain a certain number of leading zeroes).

I believe this is called a near preimage attack.

What is the current status of attacking truncated second preimages of SHA-256?

Comment: Actually, Bitcoin mining seems closer to requiring to find $X$ such that $\text{SHA-256}(\text{SHA-256}(X))<\text{target}$ (I have the details fuzzy); so the function to attack is not $\text{SHA-256}$, but rather $\text{SHA-256}^2$. In any case, I know no attack, even theoretical, on even (full) $\text{SHA-256}$.

Comment: Often referred to as `SHA-256d`

Comment: As far as I know, bitcoin mining is pretty much a brute-force effort: Try out different combinations, e.g. starting at a random value and then increment by $1$, so that you don't cover numbers that someone else already checked. There is no cryptanalysis done, or any kind of advanced attack technique.

Comment: @tylo I think the question was whether cryptanalysis techniques existed to improve upon brute force and thereby defeat the Bitcoin proof-of-work scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The current status as of the time I write this is: There are no known attacks on second pre-images for truncated SHA-256 that are faster than brute force.